# Could not cast value of type 'UIViewController' to UITableViewController

Tags: ios, iphone, swift, uiviewcontroller, collectionview

I'm trying to segue from one view controller to another, and pass data to the next controller, but I keep getting this error:

> Could not cast value of type ViewController to [VC2]

Setup looks like this:

- `NavigationController` is initial entry point to VC1
- `ViewController1` is a `collectionViewController` with show segue to VC2
- `ViewController2` is a `viewController` with only a container to embed VC3
- `ViewController3` is a `tableViewController` with static table and
  collectionView.

[image]

VC3 is my `destinationViewController` and embedded in VC2.  When I select a `collectionViewCell` from VC1 I get Signal SIGABRT.

```
override func collectionView(collectionView: UICollectionView, didSelectItemAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) {

        selectedImage = UIImage(named: wholeArray[indexPath.row]["image"] as! String)!
        selectedLabel = wholeArray[indexPath.row]["name"] as? String

        self.performSegueWithIdentifier("show", sender: nil)
    }

    override func prepareForSegue(segue: UIStoryboardSegue, sender: AnyObject!) {

    if (segue.identifier == "show") {
      let secondVC: ViewController02 = (segue.destinationViewController as? ViewController02)!

            secondVC.image = selectedImage
            secondVC.label = selectedLabel
        }
    }
```

Since `UITableViewController` is a subclass of `UIViewController`, this code should work just fine.  What am I doing wrong?

** **Updated question with type inheritance and exact error message:** **

```
class ViewController01: UICollectionViewController, UICollectionViewDataSource, UICollectionViewDelegate, UICollectionViewDelegateFlowLayout {

class ViewController02: UIViewController {

class ViewController03: UITableViewController, UICollectionViewDataSource, UICollectionViewDelegate,UIScrollViewDelegate {

class HeaderView: UIView {
```

> 2015-10-07 11:26:27.384 UITableViewHeader[45474:3576139] Unknown class _TtC17UITableViewHeader14ViewController in Interface Builder file.
>
> Could not cast value of type 'UITableViewHeader.ViewController02' (0x107a38360) to 'UITableViewHeader.ViewController03' (0x107a38a50).

Comment: class ContainerViewController: UIViewController

Comment: please include the type inheritances of the different controllers and include the EXACT error message, dont rephrase, dont retype, copy&paste it.

Comment: please edit the actual question, dont post in the comment.

Comment: In debugger I entered: po secondVC.image
error: Execution was interrupted, reason: EXC_BAD_ACCESS (code=EXC_I386_GPFLT).
The process has been returned to the state before expression evaluation.

Comment: Check the class of the view controllers in your storyboard

Comment: @Cosyn Thanks.  I checked the classes in SB and made sure they matched the signatures.

Comment: Try this link [prepare(for segue:) with navigation controller](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28788416/swift-prepareforsegue-with-navigation-controller)

Answer (score 0):

Change this line in your code

```
let secondVC: ViewController02 = (segue.destinationViewController as? ViewController02)!
```

To

```
let secondVC:ViewController02 = segue.destinationViewController as! ViewController02
```

or simple to:

```
    let secondVC = segue.destinationViewController as! ViewController02
```

Comment: Thanks William, Tried both of those and multiple other variations.  No luck and same error message.

Comment: @mvien what is the error? plus show me please the signature of `ViewControlelr02`

Comment: updated the question with signatures of all view controllers and subclass uiview.  Also included exact error message

Comment: on which class are you using the `prepareForSegue ` ?

Comment: VC1: UICollectionViewController